# siunitx round-half=even erratic behavior

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to create random exercises sheets (including answer) where students could practice rounding to the nearest integer.  These exercises round the exact half to the nearest even number.  E.g. 2.5 is rounded to 2 and 3.5 is rounded to 4.

I try to do it using the `round-half=even` option from the `siunitx` package but the results seem erratic.  From the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{round-half = even}

\begin{document}
$\num{2,6} \rightarrow \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{2,6}$

$\num{3,6} \rightarrow \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{3,6}$

$\num{12,6} \rightarrow \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{12,6}$

$\num{13,6} \rightarrow \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{13,6}$

$\num{14,6} \rightarrow \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{14,6}$

\end{document}
```

I get

2.6 is rounded to 2 (wrong)

3.6 is rounded to 4 (true)

12.6 is rounded to 12 (wrong)

13.6 is rounded to 13 (wrong)

14.6 is rounded to 14 (wrong)

Does anyone knows why such a behavior? Is there a workabout?

From `\listfiles`, this is my version of `siunitx`

```
 siunitx.sty    2018/05/17 v2.7s A comprehensive (SI) units package
```

**Edit**

@Werner didn't have the same output as me, despite having the same `siunitx` version. Here is an image showing my texcode output and `\listfiles`

[image]

Comment: thanks @Werner for the edit except that 13.6 is rounded to 13 (which is really strange)

Comment: I don't follow why you feel some of these are wrong: they are all the nearest even integer

Comment: The convention is round half to even.  The number should be rounded to the nearest interger.  But, if the decimal is exactly half, it should be round to the nearest even integer. SO 2.5 is rounded to 2 and 2.51 is rounded to 3.  And 13.6 is wrong in both cases.

Comment: Source : [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)

Comment: Interestingly, 2.6 is rounded to 2 but 2.61 to 3 ...

Comment: @AlainRemillard: When I compile your minimal document, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGvZR.png), which shows 13.6 rounds to 14 (same version of [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)).

Comment: note that it does work correctly for rounding to 1 decimal place: 0.26 rounded to 0.3 (vs. 2.6 rounded to 2), 1.36 rounded to 1.4 (vs. 13.6 rounded to 14, which is indeed correct as @Werner commented), 1.46 rounded to 1.5 (vs 14.6 rounded to 14).

Comment: @JosephWright: I think there's an interpretation difference: `half-round = even` for you means round to the nearest *even* integer. To others, `half-round = even` only applied for when you have a tie, like in `2.5` > `2`, or `13.5` > `13`. In all other non-tie cases, regular round happens to the *closest* integer.

Comment: I've checked my v3 code, which seems to get this right ... hmm ... another one of those things I need to finish v3 for :(

Comment: @Werner Funny how we don't get the same thing.  I don't know how to add an image in a comment, so I'll edit my question to add my input and output.

Comment: @AlainRemillard the precision in your last two examples is -1, that could make a difference.

Comment: Thank's @Marijn.  I tried a lot of thing and I didn't notice this small mistake in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary fix is

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_number_process_places_none:n #1
  {
    \prop_get:NnNT \l__siunitx_number_in_prop { #1 -decimal } \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \tl_head:N \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl } > 4
          {
            \prop_get:NnNTF \l__siunitx_number_in_prop { #1 -integer }
              \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl
              {
                \tl_set:Nx \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl
                  { \int_eval:n { \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl + 1 } }
                \bool_if:NF \l__siunitx_round_half_up_bool
                  {
                    \bool_lazy_and:nnT
                      {
                        \int_compare_p:nNn
                          { 0 \tl_head:N \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl } = 5
                      }
                      {
                        \int_compare_p:nNn
                          { 0 \tl_tail:N \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl } = 0
                      }
                      {
                        \int_if_odd:nT \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl
                          {
                            \tl_set:Nx \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl
                              { \int_eval:n { \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl - 1 } }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
              { \tl_set:Nn \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl { 1 } }
            \prop_put:NnV \l__siunitx_number_in_prop
              { #1 -integer } \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl
          }
          {
            \prop_if_in:NnF \l__siunitx_number_in_prop { #1 -integer }
              {
                \prop_put:Nnn \l__siunitx_number_in_prop
                  { #1 -integer } { 0 }
              }
          }
      }
    \prop_remove:Nn \l__siunitx_number_in_prop { #1 -decimal }
    \bool_if:NF \l__siunitx_process_int_to_dec_bool
      { \prop_remove:Nn \l__siunitx_number_in_prop { #1 -decimal-marker } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I will update the package on CTAN today.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution.  And mostly thanks for the `siunitx`package.